# How do you completely purge an installed aplication?

Tags: purge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

I installed UltraEditor (uex package) from a source I can't remember. Later I purged the installation with:

```
aptitude purge uex
```

The application disappeared but its name still appears when I type Alt-F2, as one of the installed applications.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: I suspect you just need to remove it from your zeitgeist history.  Does it still run if you select it?

Comment: Alt-f2 view does not list installed applications, it's an history of recently executed commands.

Comment: aking12012> No, it doesn't run, it is removed, purged.  ||  João Pinto> the item is in a list called "LIST OF KNOWN APPLICATIONS". If you are right, then it seems another typical misleading thing of the designers that very often don't call things by their name. In that case the list should be called: "List of recently used applications". SIMPLE!! hahaha

Comment: But the truth is that I think that the list is not a list of recent applications because when you run Alt+F2 in a LiveCd or in a fresh install, the list isn't empty.

Comment: Since the difference between `purge` and `remove` is that `purge` also deletes systemwide configuration files, you shouldn't necessarily expect that `purge`ing the software will keep it from appearing in a list of a *particular user*'s recent applications. If this is to be considered a bug, then it would be a bug in `unity` or whatever interface provides the list. Also, I think Alt+F2 in Unity will list recent applications, recent commands, and will also provide suggestions as you type even for applications that you haven't run recently ...but I'm not sure (I mainly use Lubuntu these days).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Synaptic Package Manager (install [synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic)).

Right-click on the package you want to purge and click Mark for Complete Removal.

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/43860/105707) for more information on what this does.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get purge <application>` or `sudo apt-get remove --purge <application>` are typical for normally installed packages.

I believe that `purge` deletes sytem-wide configuration, but not user-specific (e.g., home directory config files) for the associated application.

There may be config files left in your home directory -- for instance, in `.config` or `.local` . 
You'll probably find it easiest to run `sudo updatedb`, then run `locate <packagename>` to list out locations of remaining files.  You can grep remaining output and delete what's left.