# How to completely remove a Software

Tags: uninstall, eclipse, disk-usage

first of all merry christmas to everyone.

I wanted to ask you a basic question. I installed a software, in this case Eclipse 3.8 through the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

And the terminal told me :

```
After this operation, 236 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
```

When I want to remove it I do :

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse
```

and the terminal gives me :
    After this operation, 125 kB disk space will be freed.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y

**My question is**: how can I delete all the files I downloaded before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I hope this link helps: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135910/how-do-you-completely-purge-an-installed-aplication?lq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the correct way to completely remove an application?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/187888/what-is-the-correct-way-to-completely-remove-an-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to remove all the downloaded packages which done using either Terminal or Ubuntu Software Center, you could use the command `sudo apt-get clean`. If you want to remove everything of the installed packages, you could use the command `sudo apt-get purge {package_name}`, in your case, `sudo apt-get purge eclipse`.